# How to parameterize a helical tube with a "sine wave around a circle" cross section?

Tags: surfaces, parametric

Consider a helical tube with a circular cross section. I already can make a regular helical tube:

[what's the equation of helix surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461547/whats-the-equation-of-helix-surface)

Now, instead of a circular cross section, I want to make it have a cross section that is a sine wave imposed over a circle, so that the resulting cross section resembles a flower:

[Equation of sine wave around a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225351/equation-of-sine-wave-around-a-circle)

My two questions are:

1. How can I parameterize a helical tube that has such a cross section?
2. Is there a name for this surface?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use the equation in the answer by Jyrki Lahtonen you just need to substitute $a=a_0(1+\sin ku)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! What is the reasoning behind this substitution? And what can we call this surface?

Comment: I copy a passage from the cited answer:

>  "The key is that we get the desired surface by drawing (3D-)circles with axis direction determined by the direction of the curve, i.e. the tangent. Equivalently, we draw a circle of radius $a$ in the plane spanned by $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{b}$."

Now we draw your flowered-shaped surface instead of a circle modulating its radius.